# Is having one large motor more efficient than having two motors half the size?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors

I wanted to use multiple smaller motors to have the same strength as a large motor but spread out across a wider area. Is that as good as one large motor or is there some efficiency or power loss in doing that?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the load.

If the load is the size of the single motor then that might be better, but if the load is half the full power rating often, then using one small one and bringing in the second as needed may be better.

So you need to understand the load.

A similar situation is often found for boilers where there is a leading and lagging boiler according to the demand. Usually they rotate every so often to even out the hours. One factory had six boilers and each was lead boiler for a week.

Comment: Why is one large motor better for a load the size of the motor?

Comment: 1 efficiency value instead of 2 as for some equipment as it gets larger, the clearances get smaller in comparison.